# Why in Saleor checkout, shipment in France and other countries not working?

Tags: django, saleor

I have installed Saleor on macos High sierra for evaluation purpose

I have populated Saleor with Example Data, and everything works fine. But when I Try to checkout the process is stuck at shipping step, with the following message :

> Unfortunately we do not ship to your selected country.  Please enter
>   an alternative shipping address or contact us, if you think that's a
>   mistake.

I have try many countries but the result is the same ...

All countries are configured correctly by the Example Data

Any idea ? Does I miss something ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming

Comment: I don't agree with you, it could be setup & python configuration settings or variables or deployment ... maybe not programming, but maybe yes at this step i don't know. And I wonder how can you be so sure ?

Comment: Because your question doesn’t have any code or mention of code or code configuration, or anything even vaguely related to programming in it. The problem might be caused by something that can be fixed by programming, but of course that doesn’t mean your _question_ is about programming unless you _make_ it about programming. It’s the same as saying “my iPhone doesn’t work” and expecting someone to work that out for you here, just because iPhones have software

Comment: You where right i solve the problem it was database configuration

Answer (score 0):

The message you are seeing is strictly related to the `ShippingMethod` you have created.

This message is displayed only if no `ShippingMethod` is suitable for the order you've placed.

In Saleor, shipping methods are price based (eg. for orders of total value between 20$-200$) or weight based (eg. for orders lighter than 20kg).

Please check the shipping methods in the dashboard as probably you're not covering certain cases.

Comment: Thanks, and even if it was not about programming, your help was really appreciated